# Overriding an object that was passed to a function

Tags: javascript, object, overriding

I was wondering recently if this is possible: Passing an object to a function and overriding the entire object with a complete different object inside of that function, so that its value is permanently modified. Since objects are passed by reference, I have a feeling that it must work somehow but I have no idea how. To put it in code, it should do something like this:

```
function a() {
    console.log("i am a");
}

function b() {
    console.log("i am b");
}

function override(func1, func2) {
    func1 = func2;
}

override(a, b);

a(); //"i am b" expected
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/espkZ/)**

This obviously doesn't work because I'm just overriding the variable `func1` but I think you get the idea. And I chose to use functions instead of pure objects, because you could easily "override" an object by just deleting its properties and copying the new properties from the second object. But that's not what I want.

And before you ask, I'm not trying to solve any real life problem with this, I'm just asking out of curiosity. So is there a way to achieve this and if not, is there a reason why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because although JS passes references to functions that just means that your `func1` and `func2` parameters end up referring to the same functions (objects) that the identifiers `a` and `b` refer to but when you change what `func1` refers to that doesn't affect what `a` refers to.

To put it another way, when you pass an object to a function the function can change the content of the object by modifying, adding or deleting properties, but it can't change which object a variable outside the function refers to. (At least, not via the function's own argument - a function *can* modify variables in its scope chain up to and including global variables, but it has to do so by referring to them by their own names.)

Comment: So by doing something like `a = b`, I'm actually just modifying what `a` refers to, but not really the value that `a` refered to, until that point?

Comment: Yes, assuming we're talking objects (and not primitive number or string or whatever values) `a = b` means "change what `a` refers to so that it refers to the same thing as `b`". It doesn't have any effect on the thing `a` referred to before that _except_ that if `a` referred to an object that no other variables refer to then that object will be garbage collected.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. So there is absolutely no way to acutually change the data, that some object refers to, to something complete different? I mean, the assignment operator in my question was just to make the idea clear, but maybe there is something else one could do?

Comment: You could completely remove all of an object's properties and add back in any properties that you need, but that doesn't change which object `a` refers to, it just changes the content of that object. If `a` and `b` are global you can "cheat" and say `window.a = ` from inside the function, but obviously globals are a special case.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
function override(func1, func2) {
    func1 = func2;
}
```

`func1` is a variable that points  to function `a` and `func2` is a variable that points  to function `b`. The statement `func1 = func2` makes `func1` point to b. It does not change anything outside the function `override`.

Please use objects to make use of **pass by reference**. The code given below illustrates how it works.

```
function a() {
    console.log("i am a");
}

function b() {
    console.log("i am b");
}

var object1 = {
   func1:a
};

var object2 = {
   func2:b
}


function override(object1, object2) {
    object1.func1 = object2.func2;
}

override(object1, object2);

object1.func1(); //"i am b"
```

This code is just for demonstration, might not be useful in a real scenario.